# Adding Prefix to Firestore Default Document Id

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Regarding Firebase document Ids, I am trying to set a prefix before the default Firebase docId generation. For example, if the default document Id generated is `23492drf94fl`, then I would write it as, `somePrefix:23492drf94fl`.

Currently, I understand that there are two ways to do this: one with generating your own custom UUID on the client side with custom prefix, and another is to rewrite the document Id after initially writing it in Firestore.

Is there any shorthand method or function I could use in React (Node.js) to just use the default Firestore docId generation w/ a specified prefix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that Firestore's write throughput depends on having a uniform distribution of the document IDs, adding a prefix will significantly impact that throughput. What are you trying to accomplish by adding this prefix?

Comment: Our current project has a lot of references and pointers rather than typical denormalization of data (for privacy reasons). For example, if we were to have a `student` document, he would perhaps have references to other documents in separate collections like `MATH:235E23` or `SCI:2309F4`. If it were just a single reference, we could easily just add another `field` that describes where this document is located from, but once we have say 50 different references, it does get a little bit cluttered. By having a prefix, instead of having a separate field, we would just be able to read the prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a shorter/easier method or function that would allow you to set a prefix to the auto-generated id. You will need to do it manually as you mentioned it and even doing this manually, it's not a very good option, as you will be impacting more of your application and, of course, spending part of your [quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) on each read and write every time a new doc is created.

However, if you really would like or need, to have the document id with a prefix, I would recommend you to use a second field, where you would copy the value of the document id and then, add the prefix. This way, you won't affect the default field created - which can impact the uniform distribution of it, since it's automatically created - and you would still be able to have a `MATH:235E23` or `SCI:2309F4` your database, that you can use as a default field for you.

Besides that, in case you feel this could be a good improvement to the system, please, consider raising a Feature Request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0), so they can check about the possibility of implementing it in the future.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: In case you think my answer helped you, please, consider accepting/upvoting it.